# Why does Firefox sometimes start going into off-line mode?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

I am not doing anything to cause this as far as I can tell, but sometimes it does this a few times in a row. This happens when it has been working for some time. I checked the other notice of this problem, but mine is XP and it is not happen on a re-start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to right-click in the about:config page to open the right-click context menu and use "New > Boolean" to create a new Boolean.

Name: network.manage-offline-status
Value: false

You can also look at these two add-ons:
[StayInOnlineMode](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13233/)
[Disable Automatic Offline Management](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13152/)

Comment: The add-on “Disable Automatic Offline Management” has been removed.